# Assigning OnDrawItem to TMenuItem dynamically in C++Builder

Tags: c++builder, vcl

```
TMenuItem *mi = new TMenuItem(this);

mi->OnDrawItem = &miThemesDrawItem;
```

results in error:

> [bcc64 Error] _TForm1.cpp(280): assigning to 'Vcl::Menus::TMenuDrawItemEvent' (aka 'void ((__closure *))(System::TObject *, Vcl::Graphics::TCanvas *, const System::Types::TRect &, bool) __attribute__((fastcall))') from incompatible type 'void (__closure *)(System::TObject *, Vcl::Graphics::TCanvas *, System::Types::TRect &, bool)'

Function declaration is okay, in fact I can assign it at design-time to menu items that are available at design-time.

```
void __fastcall miThemesDrawItem(TObject *Sender, TCanvas *ACanvas, TRect &ARect, bool Selected);
```

I found a workaround. I assigned this handler at design-time on a separator item `N1`, and then at run-time I just do `mi->OnDrawItem = N1->OnDrawItem`, and it works fine since `OnDrawItem` does not get called for a menu separator, but I don't like this!

What am I missing, how to assign this handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Function declaration is okay

Actually, it is not.  Pay *very close* attention to what the error message is telling you:

> assigning to 'Vcl::Menus::TMenuDrawItemEvent' ... from incompatible type ...'

So, why is `miThemesDrawItem()` incompatible? Because it is has a different type than what `TMenuDrawItemEvent` is expecting!

Let's look at `TMenuDrawItemEvent` first.  The error message says its type is:

```cpp
void ((__closure *))(System::TObject *, Vcl::Graphics::TCanvas *, const System::Types::TRect &, bool) __attribute__((fastcall))
```

We can ignore the `__attribute__` for now, thus the type is:

```cpp
void (__closure *)(System::TObject *, Vcl::Graphics::TCanvas *, const System::Types::TRect &, bool)
```

That matches up with the *actual* declaration of `TMenuDrawItemEvent` in `Vcl.Menus.hpp`:

```cpp
typedef void __fastcall (__closure *TMenuDrawItemEvent)(System::TObject* Sender, Vcl::Graphics::TCanvas* ACanvas, const System::Types::TRect &ARect, bool Selected);
```

Now, let's look at your `miThemesDrawItem()`.  The error message says its type is:

```cpp
void (__closure *)(System::TObject *, Vcl::Graphics::TCanvas *, System::Types::TRect &, bool)
```

That matches up with your *actual* declaration:

```cpp
void __fastcall miThemesDrawItem(TObject *Sender, TCanvas *ACanvas, TRect &ARect, bool Selected);
```

Notice any differences between the declared type of `TMenuDrawItemEvent` vs the declared type of `miThemesDrawItem()`?  The `TRect` parameter in `miThemesDrawItem()` is *not* declared as `const`!

You need to declare `miThemesDrawItem()` to have the *exact same signature* as how `TMenuDrawItemEvent` is declared, eg:

```cpp
void __fastcall miThemesDrawItem(TObject* Sender, TCanvas* ACanvas, const TRect &ARect, bool Selected);
```

> in fact I can assign it at design-time to menu items that are available at design-time

That by itself doesn't guarantee that `miThemesDrawItem()` is 100% compatible with the `TMenuItem::OnDrawItem` event.  Although the IDE does validate an event handler's type when the user tries to assign it to an event at design-time, the IDE is a *little* lenient on this matter.  The IDE is relying on RTTI when performing the validation, and the RTTI is based on Delphi information, not C++ information. Const-correctness works a little differently in Delphi than in C++. So, *sometimes* the IDE does allow less-than-compatible handlers through, especially for the sake of backwards compatibility (ie, the `TRect` parameter of `TMenuDrawItemEvent` wasn't always `const`).

After validation, the IDE merely stores the *name* of the event handler into the DFM, but the actual function is not assigned to the event until run-time (since its memory address is not known at design-time). When the DFM is streamed in at run-time, the function's type will not be validated again when the function is assigned to the event, it is blindly taken as-is.  So, even at run-time, there *may* be subtle issues if the handler is not 100% compatible with the event.

The compiler, on the other hand, requires the type of a function to be 100% compatible with a function pointer that it is being assigned to.  There is no room for any differences.  So, in this case, a difference in `const` qualifiers on a parameter is a big no-no.  That is why the compiler won't let you assign `miThemesDrawItem()` to the `TMenuItem::OnDrawItem` event in your code, until you fix the signature of `miThemesDrawItem()` to match the type of `TMenuDrawItemEvent` *exactly*.

Comment: Thank you! 

Interesting was that this function was generated by the IDE, I double clicked on one of the item's handler property to generate it. I assumed nothing could be wrong with function declaration.

Comment: The auto-generation of an event handler is based on Delphi RTTI, and IIRC there are subtle issues with that process in some versions of the IDE, especially under 64bit where ABIs may be slightly different than under 32bit when it comes to passing around structures under a certain size threshold.